# Value of series $\sum_{n} \sin(\frac{\pi}{4n^2-1})\sin(\frac{2n\pi}{4n^2-1})$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Ive already shown (I think) that the series $\sum_{n} \sin(\frac{\pi}{4n^2-1})\sin(\frac{2n\pi}{4n^2-1})$ converges. But I dont know how i can find the value of this serie. Of course I should find one serie $u_n$ which verify : $\sin(\frac{\pi}{4n^2-1})\sin(\frac{2n\pi}{4n^2-1})  = u_{n+1}-u_n$, but i dont find such a series.

Ive tried trigonometric formula and things like $4n^2-1=(2n+1)(2n-1)$, but it doesnt help me...

Ty for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: apply $$\sin x \sin y = \frac12 [\cos (x-y) - \cos(x+y)]$$ to get a telescoping series.